# Why we need Weblogic Inactive Connection Timeout

Tags: database-connection, weblogic

If a connection is 'inactive' I guess the Weblogic internal data source manager should recover the connection. Why should 'Inactive Connection Timeout' be a configurable parameter. Is there any use case which requires WL to wait for certain period before an inactive connection is recovered?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This variation could occur depending on what downstream systems are doing, or where a system is sometimes under load and not able to respond in an adequate period of time

Answer (score 0):

A leaked connection is a connection that was not properly returned to the connection pool in the data source. To automatically recover leaked connections, you can specify a value for Inactive Connection Timeout on the JDBC Data Source. ( Configuration: Connection Pool page in the Administration Console.) When you set a value for Inactive Connection Timeout, WebLogic Server forcibly returns a connection to the data source when there is no activity on a reserved connection for the number of seconds that you specify. When set to 0 (the default value), this feature is turned off.

Comment: The is just a copy of reference text from the manual without providing any reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

After digging into this.. specific to question "Why should it be configurable..", because by default this feature is turned off, you can turn it on if you believe that the application for some reason is not returning connections back to the pool, i.e. 
[leaking connections](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13737/ds_tuning.htm#i1198472). Depending on the application use cases and the amount of resource leakage, one could set the duration. IOW, you don't want to timeout connections too quickly, because it will force the app server to have to recreate those on next need or cause unnecessary errors. But if the application is leaking a lot of connections, then you can tighten the duration so it keeps cleaning up.